# How to recognize an area in an canvas via javascript

Tags: javascript, html, design-patterns, canvas, image-recognition

This image is loaded in an html5 canvas.

If a user presses at any point inside the square, I want to fill this area with a color. But just inside, the color stops at the black lines. You can think about the fill tool like in Windows Paint.

How can I solve this? Are there libraries for javascript for such a function to start with?

[image: shape]

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is called a [flood fill algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill). Which basically will take the color of the pixel you clicked on as a seed. It will check for all the pixels that are connected to the seed pixel that have the same color of the seed and fill them to a desired color. There are two types of this algorithm: 8-directional and 4-directional. Where the neighbours are defined as such ( *S = Seed, X = Connected* ):

**4-directional**

```
----------------
|    |  X |    |
----------------
|  X |  S |  X |
----------------
|    |  X |    |
----------------
```

**8-directional**

```
----------------
|  X |  X |  X |
----------------
|  X |  S |  X |
----------------
|  X |  X |  X |
----------------
```

The recursive algorithm is like so (From Wikipedia):

```
Flood-fill (node, target-color, replacement-color):
 1. If target-color is equal to replacement-color, return.
 2. If the color of node is not equal to target-color, return.
 3. Set the color of node to replacement-color.
 4. Perform Flood-fill (one step to the west of node, target-color, replacement-color).
    Perform Flood-fill (one step to the east of node, target-color, replacement-color).
    Perform Flood-fill (one step to the north of node, target-color, replacement-color).
    Perform Flood-fill (one step to the south of node, target-color, replacement-color).
 5. Return.
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use the [CanvasRenderingContext2D.isPointInPath()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/isPointInPath)

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.clicked = false;

function draw() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.save();
  ctx.rotate(45);
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.rect(100, -100, 100, 100);
  if (ctx.clicked) {
    ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
    ctx.fill()
  }
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.restore();
}
draw();
canvas.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  var bounds= canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  var mouseXY = [e.clientX-bounds.left, e.clientY-bounds.top]
  ctx.clicked = ctx.isPointInPath(mouseXY[0], mouseXY[1]);
  draw();
});
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" height="500" width="500"></canvas>
```